# How can I use the API to set a field to NULL on an existing record?

Tags: api

Let's say I have a contact which exists and has `id = 12345`. I can use the API like this...

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'create', {"id": 12345, "nick_name": "Bob"});
```

to change the contact's nick name. Cool.

---

But when I try this...

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'create', {"id": 12345, "nick_name": null});
```

the call completes with success but does *not* set the `nick_name` field to `NULL` as I'd expect. Why? Is there some other way I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't quite feel right to me on the empty vs null front - playing around with the API explorer in 4.7.15, but what I can say is if I do an api call for a contact ID (say, 3) with nickname IS NULL as follows:

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'get', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "id": 3,
  "nick_name": {"IS NULL":1}
})
```

I come up with the result for cid 3 including `"nick_name": "",` (which would say to me that it's *empty* instead of IS NULL... but comes up with the previous api call anyways.

Then I run the following test by adding a nickname:

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'create', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "contact_type": "Individual",
  "id": 3,
  "nick_name": "nickname"
})
```

and run the same GET query as above, and get no results as follows:

```
{
    "is_error": 0,
    "version": 3,
    "count": 0,
    "values": []
}
```

If I then run:

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'create', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "contact_type": "Individual",
  "id": 3,
  "nick_name": ""
})
```

and run the first GET query... I come up with the same result as the beginning again... which appears to be a contact with nickname empty ("") rather than null.

**TLDR;** It looks like you can use

```
CRM.api3('Contact', 'create', {
  "sequential": 1,
  "contact_type": "Individual",
  "id": 3,
  "nick_name": ""
})
```

even though it doesn't feel quite right... if you're trying to pull that contact up with "nickname IS NULL" searches using the api.

Comment: This is cool. To my surprise, supplying an empty string for the field value, actually does set the field to `NULL`, and it works for other non-string field types like `int` and `datetime`.

Comment: Sounds like it's a feature! Thanks for confirming :)